# TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION Sensor values changes according to smartphone brand - model

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors

I published a game that uses motion sensors two days ago on Google Play Store. This game is a boxer game and allows users when they shake smartphone score will be evaluated automatically. To evaluate score, it uses **TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION** sensor.

But the problem is after I published the game, some of users send their score. I saw that for some smartphones it is easy to get 900 points when for some smartphones it is hard to get 500 points. I mean that, if the same user shake(with same force) different phones in this game; for X smartphone he gets (for example) 400 points, for Y smartphone the gets (for example) 850 points.

Why does this inequality occur?

I understood(guess) that some smartphones evaluates score less, when some smartphones evaluates score more.

My implentation (roughly)

```
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

-

```
@Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) {
                float[] values = event.values;
                 float x = values[0];//to get X - axis acceleration   
                  //.......

                 //........
    }
    }
```

I can share my application link, but is it allowed? If yes, please say. I can share my application link.

Note: I want to explain my algorithm, to get score I get the maximum acceleration from sensor and keep the maximum value in a variable. after the user click show score button, I multiply by 40 and get score.

Comment: All these phones use different sensors, so of course they'll have different lag, ringing behavior, sensitivities, etc.  In  particular they'll have different maximums-  there is only so much you can accelerate an accelerometer before it reaches its maximum value,  It could be you've capped out the sensors with a lower value.

Comment: The best approach for this question.

Comment: Who says they will have different maximums? Is there any border for acceleration sensor for different phones?

Comment: The spec sheets.  Different phones use different accelerometers from different manufacturers.  Even between two instances of the same model there will be small differences, but between two different models of accelerometers they will have very different maximums and sensitivities because they're designed differently.

Comment: You may be interested in http://www.modalshop.com/filelibrary/DecodingAccelSpecSheetIMACXXXVII.pdf

Comment: BTW< maxing out is why Nintendo added a second accelerometer in those Wii remote extention packs.  The original acelerometer had good sensitivity but was easy to max out, which would show up in games as constant movement or no movement.  THey added a second one with less sensitivity bu higher max range in order to detect high acceleration movements that would just read as ACCEL_MAX on the original hardware.

Comment: So what is a solution ? What can I do to solve this problem? This game should be fair.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your question. Type_Linear_Acceleration is a virtual sensor that gets its data from a combination of data from the accelerometer and the gyroscope.

Most smartphone accelerometer and gyroscopes do not have the exact same sensor, and obviously the data will be slightly different between each device.

Comment: From scientific perspective I think they should be SAME. Why? I think, all of them should be instant acceleration. Science show that objects have (just ONE) acceleration in an instant like speed. Then why do different phones show different results? (I do not mean sensitivity, probably they will be different) 
My question is simple, if we apply same force(in same direction) to 2 different smartphone why are their score different? 
This difference sometimes can be 3 times bigger.

Comment: F = m.a please suppose that their M is same (mass.)

Comment: When I was saying SAME I mean they should show NEAR results. For example, " suppose 1st phone shows 512, 2nd shows 530" this result is expected. But there is huge difference for different phones. 
This difference sometimes can be 3 times bigger(roughly). I tested.

Comment: Are you using a testing rig to ensure you apply the same force every time in the same amount of time (so equal jerk)?  If not, I assure you you are *not* applying the same force each time.

Answer (score 1):

Your haven't described how you calculate the score.
I would do a square root calculation of the 3 dimensions, and then use the result (the magnetude) as the score

```
score = getMagnetude(values);
```

and the function:

```
private float getMagnetude(float[] v) {
        return Math.sqrt( v[0]*v[0] + v[1]*v[1] + v[2]*v[2] );
}
```

Comment: This question is not about how to calculate, I am calculating using just 1 direction(X axis). It is not problem. My question is that "Why don't different phones show NEAR results?" "Why the difference can be huge? for same acceleration" I tested. In fact, I can share my application link, if it is not forbidden.

Answer (score -1):

I understood my problem. I am using **Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION** so it uses Gyroscope + Accelerometer sensor.

**What is the operation logic of TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION sensor?**

It uses accelerometer and gyroscope sensor.It have a formula that:

Linear Acceleration = k1 x accelerometer  + k2 xgyroscope

k1 and k2 is constant values.

For gyroscope there is no any maximum(I think) value but for accelerometer sensor different smartphone uses different maximum value.

These maximum values are -+g(9.8), -+2g, -+4g and -+8g.

Finally, for different smartphones different results is shown because users **usually** reach the maximum value when they shake their smartphone.